# Creating yyyy-mm-dd column in attribute table from Julian day in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, date, timemanager

I am using the time manager for a set of data and I need to create a column in my attribute table of the date in the format yyyy-mm-dd.  I already have a column in my attribute table that contains Julian days (e.g. values of 1, 2, 3, etc. that I want to correspond to 2010-01-01, 2010-01-02, 2010-01-3, etc. respectively).  I've tried using the field calculator to do this using [Converting from Julian Date to Calendar Date?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93200) but I was unable to get an output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach, assuming your *Day 1* starts on `2010-01-01`.

```
to_date(to_date('2010-01-01') + to_interval(concat(to_string(("j_day" - 1)), ' days')))
```

`j_day` is your Julian day field

Comment: Nicer, saves some typing

Comment: Thanks @BERA I wish I could do programming ... it will be my New Year resolution next year...

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I'm unfamiliar with programming so this is more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks @racheldeep for this interesting subject. It gave me opportunity to learn about calendar and Julian day (a.k.a. ordinal date).

Answer (score 3):

Add a date field

Use Field Calculator with function editor (change the start date, dont know what you want) and press blue play button on top:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import datetime

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def jtogreg(x, feature, parent):
    startdate=datetime.datetime(2000,1,1)
    d=startdate+datetime.timedelta(x)
    return str(d)
```

[image]

The function can now be found under 'Custom'. Call the function:

```
 jtogreg(  "JDays" )
```

[image]